# A General Wordpress question, but related to Traveler Envato Theme: modification of texts overwrites due to version updates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, updates, overwrite

I am using a hotel booking theme from Envato.
I wanted to repurpose it for a specific need.
The theme provides a lot of functionality beyond the base Wordpress install as you can imagine being a hotel booking them.

I wanted to go through the site and manually replace every instance of the word "Hotel" with "Spa".

However, I have a feeling that with the next theme update I will lose all of that, and it will reset from "Spa" to "Hotel".

Is that what will happen, and is there a way to avoid modifications to a theme from being wiped out?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is if your theme provided language file (e.g. en_US.po), you can edit it with [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) by replace "Hotel" with "Spa" then updload both .po and .mo files to your theme language folder.

Alternative way is you should create a child-theme, copy any theme files which contained the word "Hotel", then manually edit it.

These ways will remain your changes for next theme update.

Ref: https://wplang.org/translate-theme-plugin/